# Div not inline when window gets smaller?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having a small issue with a couple divs. I have it set up with 5 divs all different colors, when the window size is shrunk the divs drop down under each other one by one. Is there a way I can make the space between them shrinks with it so they but up closer?

Thanks again guys

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.pageColourOn {
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.pageColourOff {
  display: none;
}

#pageName {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#pageName p {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #565656;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg01Off {
  background-color: #80b3ff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg02Off {
  background-color: #afe9af;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg03Off {
  background-color: #ffb380;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg04Off {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg05Off {
  background-color: #eeaaff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageColourOn" id="pageColour">
  <div id="pageName">
    <p>Colour</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div id="bg01" class="bg01Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg02" class="bg02Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg03" class="bg03Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg04" class="bg04Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg05" class="bg05Off">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try using [flexbox layouts](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the container `center` to a flexbox with the following properties:

```
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4%
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.pageColourOn {
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.pageColourOff {
  display: none;
}

#pageName {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#pageName p {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #565656;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bgOff {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg01Off {
  background-color: #80b3ff;
}

.bg02Off {
  background-color: #afe9af;

}

.bg03Off {
  background-color: #ffb380;
}

.bg04Off {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
}

.bg05Off {
  background-color: #eeaaff;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4%
}
```

```html
<div class="pageColourOn" id="pageColour">
  <div id="pageName">
    <p>Colour</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div id="bg01" class="bgOff bg01Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg02" class="bgOff bg02Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg03" class="bgOff bg03Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg04" class="bgOff bg04Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg05" class="bgOff bg05Off">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query, so that after a certain width of screen the elements will get a margin-bottom that is a percentage instead of px.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to make elements respond as the width of the viewport changes for example:

```
body {
background-color: lightgreen;
     }

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

This would make the background color change when the width of the viewport goes below 500 px. You can use this same concept with the width of your divs.

** Also, check out Bootstrap. Bootstrap makes it easy to define widths of elements using a grid system. You are trying to make your site "RESPONSIVE" which is a well-known concept in web dev. Bootstrap has an already created library for this problem. It use media queries to do it. It is worth understanding media queries deeply, but for a quick fix, research bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a rule in a media query that reduces the margins like in my example (last rule):

```css
  p {
  margin: 0;
}

.pageColourOn {
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.pageColourOff {
  display: none;
}

#pageName {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#pageName p {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #565656;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg01Off {
  background-color: #80b3ff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg02Off {
  background-color: #afe9af;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg03Off {
  background-color: #ffb380;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg04Off {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg05Off {
  background-color: #eeaaff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .bg01Off,
  .bg02Off,
  .bg03Off,
  .bg04Off,
  .bg05Off {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pageColourOn" id="pageColour">
  <div id="pageName">
    <p>Colour</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div id="bg01" class="bg01Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg02" class="bg02Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg03" class="bg03Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg04" class="bg04Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg05" class="bg05Off">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table instead of the `.center` div, and give it the following styles:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  width: 20%; /* This is 100/the number of <td>'s you have in the table. */
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.pageColourOn {
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.pageColourOff {
  display: none;
}

#pageName {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#pageName p {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #565656;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg01Off {
  background-color: #80b3ff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg02Off {
  background-color: #afe9af;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg03Off {
  background-color: #ffb380;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg04Off {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg05Off {
  background-color: #eeaaff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageColourOn" id="pageColour">
  <div id="pageName">
    <p>Colour</p>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="bg01" class="bg01Off">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="bg02" class="bg02Off">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="bg03" class="bg03Off">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="bg04" class="bg04Off">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="bg05" class="bg05Off">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove margin left & right and use flexbox on .center like this :

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.pageColourOn {
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.pageColourOff {
  display: none;
}

#pageName {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#pageName p {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #565656;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg01Off {
  background-color: #80b3ff;
}

.bg02Off {
  background-color: #afe9af;
}

.bg03Off {
  background-color: #ffb380;
}

.bg04Off {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
}

.bg05Off {
  background-color: #eeaaff;
}

.bg05Off, .bg04Off, .bg03Off, .bg02Off, .bg01Off {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageColourOn" id="pageColour">
  <div id="pageName">
    <p>Colour</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div id="bg01" class="bg01Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg02" class="bg02Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg03" class="bg03Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg04" class="bg04Off">
    </div>
    <div id="bg05" class="bg05Off">
    </div>
  </div>
```